# cakephp find() not returning any result for calculated offset

Tags: php, variables, cakephp, integer

I have a strange problem with my find() function in cakephp. I have following code :

```
 $page_num = (!isset($_GET["page_num"]) || $_GET["page_num"] == "") ? 2 : $_GET["page_num"];
   $page_size = 3;

   $offset = ($page_num-1)*$page_size;
   //var_dump($offset); outputs int 3
   //$offset = 3; <-- Working
   $gal_providers = 
            $this->GalProvider->find("all",array('conditions' => $conditions,'limit' => $page_size,'offset' => $offset));
```

If I define `$offset = 3` manually its showing the results, but the `$offset` I got after calciulation its not working !! What might be the problem ?

Comment: why are you using $_GET?

Comment: $log = $this->GalProvider->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
debug($log);

Use above after your query.This will print your mysql query.Then run that directly.And see if that works or not

Answer (score 2):

[Use the build in paginator of CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Don't use super globals but the request and response objects CakePHP provides.

Your code is inconsistant formatted and does not follow the CakePHP coding standard and conventions as well.